# JavaScript code src issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I separate this code, by putting all the `<script>` code from `index.html` to `javascript.js` script separately the code doesn't work.

I wrote the src address of the js file, tested the link with an alert but when I put the `<script>` code it doesn't work.

It works only if it is in `index.html` between `<script>` tag. Can someone help me to understand why? Because i need to separate and I don't know how to make it work.

After separating i obtain this.

**Index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="function.js"></script>


    </head>
<body >
    <div id="container"></div>
     <input type="button" id="tango" value="Tango!">


</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript File:**

```
function init(){
          sw=innerWidth;
          sh=innerHeight;
        $('#container').css('width',sw);
        $('#container').css('height',sh);

        }
$(document).ready(init)


var colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple'];

      function getRandomColor() {
          return colors[Math.round(Math.random() * 5)];
      }

      function tango(layer) {     
        for(var n = 0; n < layer.getChildren().length; n++) {
          var color = Kinetic.Util.getRGB(getRandomColor());
          var shape = layer.getChildren()[n];
          var stage = shape.getStage();
          var radius = Math.random() * 100 + 20;

          new Kinetic.Tween({
            node: shape, 
            duration: 1,
            x: Math.random() * stage.width(), 
            y: Math.random() * stage.height(), 
            rotation: Math.random() * 360, 
            radius: radius,
            opacity: (radius - 20) / 100,
            easing: Kinetic.Easings.EaseInOut,
            fillRed: color.r,
            fillGreen: color.g,
            fillBlue: color.b
          }).play();
        }
      }
      var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: innerWidth,
        height: innerHeight
      });

      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

      for(var n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
        var radius = Math.random() * 100 + 50;
        var color = Kinetic.Util.getRGB(getRandomColor());
        var shape = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
          x: Math.random() * stage.getWidth(),
          y: Math.random() * stage.getHeight(),
          sides: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5 + 3),
          radius: radius,
          fillRed: color.r,
          fillGreen: color.g,
          fillBlue: color.b,
          opacity: (radius - 20) / 100,
          draggable: true
        });

        layer.add(shape);
      }

      stage.add(layer);

      document.getElementById('tango').addEventListener('click', function() {
        tango(layer);
             }, false);
```

Console says me that Uncaught TypeError:

> Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: Check out your browser console.

Comment: Could you edit the question and include all source files, the html and js, and the file names?  Seeing your "before" file doesn't help people help you. They need to see all the multiple files, after you separate. If this is too hard, try setting up the code on http://jsfiddle.net and post the link.

Comment: What is external file name is it`function.js` or something else?

Comment: It is function.js the reference works, i tested with an Alert

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're putting the script tag referencing the external js file in the HEAD section? If you do this, when the script finishes loading (and executing) yout button does not exists. If this is the case, either you put the script reference in the same place (at the end of the document) of you wrap the code in a load event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake, i needet to put the script in js file in a function :

```
window.onload = function() {
}
```

I am  running the code before the DOM is constructed. I tried running my code in a window.onload handler function (but see note below) and it worked!